# Getting the date format in VBA in the correct form

Tags: vba, date

I am trying to reference a file that has the date of the previous Friday at the end in the form of mm.dd.yy.

I need to now take that date and add it to the end of a string, to end of a string in order to open select the other workbook. This is what I have right now.

File Name:
Submittals Wk Ending 06.02.17.xlsx

This is what I have so far

```
Dim wrbk As String
Dim weekdate As String

range("a1").value="=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())-1"
weekdate = Range("a1").Value    
'range("b1").value="06.02.17"
'weekdate = Range("b1").Value

msgbox weekdate 'use to check what the date format is

wrbk = "Submittals Wk Ending " & weekdate

Windows(wrbk & ".xlsx").Activate
```

When I read it from B2 with the typed in format of 06.02.17 it works, however no matter what I do, I cannot get it to read it from A1 because it changes the format to m/d/yyyy. I have tried to copy it and paste as value. Nothing seems to work.

I have the other workbook open as well when I try to run it.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You could either format the date as you use it using `wrbk = "Submittals Wk Ending " & Format(weekdate, "mm.dd.yy")` (but I would recommend you declare `weekdate As Date` if you do so, so that VBA doesn't have to convert to a string and then convert back again) or you could read the value as it was formatted in the cell using `weekdate = Range("a1").Text`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Range("A1").Value = Format$(Date - Weekday(Date) - 1, "MM.DD.YY")
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the previous Friday of any date, try below UDF. This should work fine if the Date NumberFormat is same as your System's Date format. The key is the `CDate()` which converts according to System's Date format which Office apps defaults to.

```
Option Explicit

Function GetLastFridayDate(AnyDate As Variant) As Date
    Dim dInput As Date, dLastFriday As Date
    dInput = CDate(AnyDate)
    dLastFriday = dInput - Weekday(dInput) + vbFriday - IIf(Weekday(dInput) > vbFriday, 0, 7)
    GetLastFridayDate = dLastFriday
End Function
```